# Default Richfaces Jquery not loaded in the page

Tags: jquery, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm facing a really weird issue. I'm building a web application using jsf 1.2 and richfaces 3.3.3. I haven't loaded any external jquery versions, but rather stuck to the default one provided by rich faces , ie jquery version 1.3.2. I access the default jquery by using the 'jQuery' keyword.

I have included a few javascript files on the top of my page which contains jquery in it.
When i remove all richfaces components from that page, it looks like the jquery isnt loaded. That is on the console, i see the message 'jQuery is undefined'. But when i include 'rich:extendedDataTable' tag in my page, this error vanishes. The wierd thing is that, the error still persists if i include 'rich:dataTable'. It looks like jQuery is loaded in my page only when i use 'rich:extendedDataTable'. So what i do now is put a 'rich:extendedDataTable' on that page for mo reason and render is as 'False'. I'm not sure how this makes sense.

The jsf includes on top of the page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                            xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                            xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
                            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">    
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link href="../../styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="../../styles/Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src ="first.js" language="JavaScript"/>
        <script src ="second.js" language="JavaScript"/>
        <script src ="validation.js" language="JavaScript"/>
```

The error that  see on the console is 
*ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined*

What is happening here?. Wy does it look like jquery is loaded only when i include a particular rich components. How do I make usre jQuery is avaiable on my apge bby default even though there are no rich components loaded in that page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RichFaces adds an import for JQuery only if it needs for itself. You have to force RichFaces to load JQuery even if you don't use any RichFaces component using JQuery.

You can force import of JQuery by writing this:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>
```

If you search for this code, you will find lot of examples.

Comment: Well.. that did it... thanks a lot .. never released that i could force richfaces to load jquery onto a page this way.. u saved me a lotta time..